# IBM Watson Studio: How to run a specific file deployed using .tar.gz

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, mathematical-optimization, ibm-watson, cplex

I have 2 files main.py and sub1.py. I have added these 2 files into a .tar.gz format file and deployed these to IBM Watson Studio.

Now I need to run main.py which will call the external application API to get the input data, consume/process it. The main.py file is calling methods methods from sub1.py file.

I am using a CPLEX solver to optimize the data and prepare the results back in JSON format. I am able to run this on my local machine as well as the Google Server.

Eseentially, this model will be called from an external API then model will get data by calling this API's get method, process, optimize and prepare the results to post back to API's post method.

Is there any way I could call main.py from an external API or how could I run it in IBM Cloud?

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but if your Decision Optimization model is deployed in Watson Studio, there are materials that explain how to deploy the code in WML:
https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/migrate-your-python-code-for-do-in-wml-v2-instances-710025796f7